# Excel conditional formatting rule Openpyxl or Pandas

Tags: pandas, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a conditional formatting rule for a Cell using openpyxl or Pandas.
The rule I want to write into the Excel file is: if the value of the cell is less than 1, to format it as % and if it's higher than 1 then to format it as a number.
All my attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

```
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add(cell, CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['1'], stopIfTrue=True, format='0.0%'))
```

or

```
cell = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.conditional_format(cell,{'format':'0.00%}))
```

Comment: Pandas uses openpyxl or excelwriter in the background, so always best using these directly for more control.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this you'd need two CF rules, one for values less than 1 and one for values 1 and greater.
Also given the formatting requirement, use DifferentialStyle.

The following code example will add two values to a new sheet in a new workbook;
A1 = 0.4
A2 = 1.4
Then applies two CF rules to the range A1:A2 as specified in the question; *The rule I want to write into the Excel file is: if the value of the cell is less than 1, to format it as % and if it's higher than 1 then to format it as a number.*

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.styles.numbers import NumberFormat


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

### Write some values to the sheet for testing
ws['A1'].value = 0.4
ws['A2'].value = 1.4

### Set up the rule for percentage format (where values are < 1)
p_number_format = NumberFormat(10, '0.00%')
rule1 = CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=[1], stopIfTrue=True)
rule1.dxf = DifferentialStyle(numFmt=p_number_format)

### Set up the rule for number format (where values are >= 1)
n_number_format = NumberFormat(2, '0.00')
rule2 = CellIsRule(operator='greaterThanOrEqual', formula=[1], stopIfTrue=True)
rule2.dxf = DifferentialStyle(numFmt=n_number_format)

### Write rules to sheet
ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A2', rule1)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A2', rule2)

### Save sheet
wb.save("cf_test.xlsx")
```

Example Output
[image: Example Output]

Then if you were to change the value of either cell so it's value is less than 1 the value will display as a percentage or if 1 or greater as a number

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked marvelously!